# Как решить проблему с Imagemagick на Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

Делаю проект и начались проблемы с imagemagick. На сайте,когда нажимаешь на кнопку Upload, выбираешь картинки, далее жмешь Save и ниже должны красиво отобразиться картинки, а вместо этого просто пусто.
Сам же imagemagick я установил. Paperclip версии 5.0.0.
Вот так должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя модель photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

И самое удивительно, что когда стоят styles в модели, то картинки не загружаются и бьет ошибку в консоле:

```
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
```

Но как только удаляешь из модели строку стилей:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :room

      has_attached_file :image
      validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Вот что пишут логи:

```
    Started PATCH "/rooms/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-20 01:41:54 -0700
Processing by RoomsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LMHlWcnFi7NlGh37ZgNGKORN4VPeM4nLbAyQ3Zka4dCgG0jq2yMK/7aiJwDwka3pvI9xVnC1up3jy2iuwvdQFg==", "room"=>{"home_type"=>"Apartament", "room_type"=>"Private", "accommodate"=>"4", "bed_room"=>"2", "bath_room"=>"2", "listing_name"=>"fdg", "summary"=>"gfgf", "address"=>"gfgfgdf", "is_tv"=>"1", "is_kitchen"=>"0", "is_internet"=>"0", "is_heating"=>"0", "is_air"=>"1", "price"=>"30", "active"=>"0"}, "images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005cbbce0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170420-53416-12vrrk9.jpg>, @original_filename="067c8ec7_original.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"067c8ec7_original.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mRoom Load (12.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (4.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[36mUser Load (2.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (4.4ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (1.2ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/e451414538be5739f78f86efdac7993c20170420-53416-1qdbl6k.jpg'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/e451414538be5739f78f86efdac7993c20170420-53416-mv0yk3.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/e451414538be5739f78f86efdac7993c20170420-53416-mv0yk3.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/e451414538be5739f78f86efdac7993c20170420-53416-q86bu3.jpg'
  [1m[35m (2.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/rooms/2/edit
Completed 302 Found in 786ms (ActiveRecord: 33.1ms)


Started GET "/rooms/2/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-20 01:41:55 -0700
Processing by RoomsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mRoom Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (6.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering rooms/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mPhoto Load (5.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."room_id" = $1[0m  [["room_id", 2]]
  Rendered photos/_list.html.erb (20.5ms)
  Rendered rooms/_form.html.erb (87.0ms)
  Rendered rooms/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (91.9ms)
  Rendered nav/_navbar.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered nav/_message.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 548ms (Views: 489.1ms | ActiveRecord: 14.3ms)
```

Все картинки загружаются. Помогите решить проблему, тк эти стили мне необходимы в будущем.

Comment: С картинками у вас не задалось. Пожалуйста, логи, ошибки и вывод консоли прикладывайте текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: [Народ рапортует](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1405), что переустановка или обновление ImageMagick это обычно решает.

Comment: Пробовал переустанавливать, та же история.

Comment: Допишите в вопрос ОС и пройдитесь по всему тикету по ссылке выше. Там кто-то вручную пробовал делать `identify` на файле, и вы попробуйте. Это может открыть новые детали.

Comment: Решил данную проблему!Оказывается был еще установлен один ImageMagick и его я не заметил. Все удалил и установил заново, и все заработало)Радости не было предела))Спасибо всем.